# Parsing HTML page

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing

I have a slight problem at parsing one HTML page.

Here is script i have made so far.

```
<?php

include('simple_html_dom.php');

$resoults = array();

$URL = "http://www.ajpes.si/eobjave/rezultati.asp?podrobno=0&id_skupina=51&TipDolznika=-1&TipPostopka=-1&id_SkupinaVrsta=-1&id_skupinaPodVrsta=-1&Dolznik=&Oblika=&MS&DS=&StStevilka=&Sodisce=-1&DatumDejanja_od=&DatumDejanja_do=&sys_ZacetekObjave_od=26.6.2014&sys_ZacetekObjave_do=26.6.2014&MAXREC=7000&mdres=3";

getResoults($URL);

function getResoults($URL) 
{

     global $resoults;

     $html = new simple_html_dom();
     $html->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 

     $html->load_file($URL);

     $items = $html->find("td.tabData a");  


    foreach($items as $key => $post) 
     {
         $resoults[][] = array($post->plaintext);     
     }

        $html->clear(); 
        unset($html);

        print_r(array_values($resoults[1]));
        print_r(array_values($resoults[2]));
        print_r(array_values($resoults[3]));    
        print_r(array_values($resoults[4]));
        print_r(array_values($resoults[5]));
        print_r(array_values($resoults[6]));

}

?>
```

What i currently get is a array of results ranging from 1 ...  XX

What i need is a two dimensional array ... first dimension will be at which `<tr></tr>` block i am:

and second array will store values of each result i find:

So for example values should be stored like this:

```
Array[1][0] 
Array[1][1] 
Array[1][2]
```

And for next  node:

```
Array[2][0] 
Array[2][1] 
Array[2][2]
```

If someone could help me that would be great!

Thank you all for your time!

Comment: did you try `$resoults[$key][] = array($post->plaintext);` ?

Comment: @andrew that would not work since it would return the key of the td, not the tr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to find all tr's first, then go to all td's in that tr.

Replace this:

```
$items = $html->find("td.tabData a");  

foreach($items as $key => $post) 
 {
     $resoults[][] = array($post->plaintext);     
 }
```

With this example code:

```
$tableRows = $html->find("tr");

foreach ($tableRows as $rowKey => $rowValue)
{
    static $i = 0;

    $tds = $rowValue->find("td.tabData a");

    // tr does not have any td's of that class
    if (count($tds) == 0)
        continue;

    foreach($tds as $key => $post) 
    {
        $resoults[$i][] = $post->plaintext; 
    }  
    $i++;
}
```

The complete `$resoults` array now looks like this:

> Array (
>
> ```
> [0] => Array
>     (
>         [0] => postopek osebnega stečaja
>         [1] => Borka Bolić
>         [2] => ni vpisa
>         [3] => ni javna
>         [4] => 2084/2013
>         [5] => 24.6.2014
>     )
>
> [1] => Array
>     (
>         [0] => stečajni postopek nad pravno osebo
>         [1] => PROTOCOL, protokolarni prevozi in poslovne storitve, d.o.o. - v stečaju
>         [2] => 5670829000
>         [3] => 28282345
>         [4] => 2523/2013
>         [5] => 4.6.2014
>     )
>
> [2] => Array
>     (
>         [0] => stečajni postopek nad pravno osebo
>         [1] => Lira skupina, trgovina in storitve d.o.o.
>         [2] => 5462975000
>         [3] => 20767285
>         [4] => 2328/2013
>         [5] => 31.5.2014
>     )
> ```
>
> )

Is that what you are looking for?